# How to handle fragment in activity

Tags: android

I have an activity named "Sign In" having two buttons(`signIn` and `SkipNow`).

When `skipNow` clicked `MainActivity` opens with "FindFacilityFragment" in it and
while clicking `signIn` button i want to open MainActivity with MyAccountFragment in it.

I handled `skipNow` button click by inflating fragment in onCreate method of MainActivity but i am not able to handle the second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send some parameter with intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity .class);
intent.putExtra("isSingedIn", true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in MainActivity onCreate method check it like

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean isSingedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("isSingedIn", false);
```